# NestJS - Pass user data from custom auth guard to resolvers

Tags: graphql, jwt, nestjs

I know this question gets asked frequently for the default passport AuthGuard('yourStrategy'),
but haven't found the answer for custom auth guards yet.

Why I use a custom auth guard? Because the default one and GraphQL seems to be unable to work together.
Since some update on GraphQL's side, the default AuthGuard cannot read the header any more.

I need to pass the user data, which I got from the bearer token, somehow to the resolvers.
How is passport doing this? How would you do this? I'm pretty new to nestJS and the lack of dockumentation and / or propper tutorials drives me crazy.

Relevant code:

auth.guard.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(readonly jwtService: JwtService/*, readonly userService: UsersService*/) { }
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
        const request = ctx.getContext().request;
        const Authorization = request.get('Authorization');

        if (Authorization) {
            const token = Authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');
            const { userId, firstName } = this.jwtService.verify(token)  as { userId: string; firstName: string } ;

            return !!userId;
        }
    }
}
```

jwt.strategy.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: jwtConstants.secret,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload) {
    return {userId: payload.userId, firstName: payload.firstName};
  }
}
```

auth.module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        forwardRef(() => UserModule) , 
        PassportModule.register({
            defaultStrategy: 'jwt'
        }), 
        JwtModule.register({
            secret: jwtConstants.secret,
            signOptions: {expiresIn: 3600}
        })],
    providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy, AuthResolver, AuthGuard],
    exports: [AuthService, JwtModule, AuthGuard]
})
export class AuthModule {

}
```

example resolver

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
@Resolver((of) => UserSchema)
export class UserResolver {
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

  // ===========================================================================
  // Queries
  // ===========================================================================

 @Query(() => UserDto, {description: 'Searchs for a user by a given id'})
    async getUserById(@Args('id') id: string) {

     /*
      * Instead of passing the userID as an query argument, get it from the bearer token / auth guard!
      */
      const result = await this.userService.findById(id);
      if(result) return result;
      return new NotFoundException('User not found!');
    }
}
```

Thanks for help in advance! ;-)

Edit: In case you need to see more code, you could use my github repo: https://github.com/JensUweB/ExamAdmin-Backend

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I have found a solution to this myself. I found a workaround to get the passport AuthGuard back to work with GraphQL. And for the userId: use a custom User Decorator: [github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/48#issuecomment-420693225](http://Never%20mind.%20I%20have%20found%20a%20solution%20to%20this%20myself.%20I%20found%20a%20workaround%20to%20get%20the%20passport%20AuthGuard%20back%20to%20work%20with%20GraphQL.%20And%20for%20the%20userId:%20use%20a%20custom%20User%20Decorator:%20github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/48#issuecomment-420693225)